# Finding the boundaries of a triple integral

Tags: integration

> Let $K$ be a homogenous body (i.e. it has a constant density $\rho$) that is bounded by the planes $z^2 = 2x, z = 0, x^2+y^2=x$. Find the moment of inertia regarding the $z-$axis.

Based on the lecture I suppose that I should compute

$$\int\int\int_B  r^2\rho \ dV.$$

This means we have to compute the integral

$$\int_{z_1}^{z_2} \int_{y_1(z)}^{y_2(z)} \int_{x_1(y,z)}^{x_2(y,z)} f(x,y,z)\ dx \ dy \ dz$$

However, I do not see how we could set the boundaries of the integral here. Could you help me?

Comment: Is the third boundary equation $x^2+y^2=z$?

Comment: No, it is $...=x$ as written above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your domain is a cylinder of center $ (\frac{1}{2},0)$ and radios $\frac{1}{2}$ limited by the plan $z=0$ and the surface $z=\sqrt{2x}$. So using the cylindrical coordinate we will find the following  integral boundaries:

$$0 \leq r \leq \frac{1}{2}$$and $$ 0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{2x}$$